# asp.net gridview null when running on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, gridview, checkbox

So, i have a `GridView` based on database data with `CheckBox column` in an asp.net website. 
the user can check the `checkbox` and then i save the changes to the db.

locally everything works great. but, when i publish the website to a IIS server- that's when the problems start- in the event viewer i keep on getting the following exception when the user tries saving his changes: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index` 
which means the gridview is empty when is trying to save it.
now, i read about it a little and apparently in `PostBack` the `GridView DataSource` doesn't keep his values. so how come it works perfectly when i run the website locally? and more then that- i saw many examples online that do the same things and it works for them e.g. [gridView with checkBox](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx).

My code:

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdDataBuffer" Visible="true" >
  <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxColumnDb" runat="server" HeaderText="check" ReadOnly="True"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Save button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" class="Common_Button" runat="server" Text="update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Visible="false"/>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        grdDataBuffer.DataSource = null;
        grdDataBuffer.DataBind();
        dv = BL.Process_BL.GetInfo;
        grdDataBuffer.DataSource = dv;
        grdDataBuffer.DataBind();
     }
 }

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ON IIS SERVER  grdDataBuffer.Rows.Count = 0- ALWAYS!
    for (int i = 0; i < grdDataBuffer.Rows.Count; i++) 
    {
        CheckBox chk =(CheckBox)grdDataBuffer.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[1];
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
           //does the whole logic and saves it
        }
    }
}
```

Any one?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you share your code so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: Have you updated your SQL connection string in the Web.Config? (If you have one).

Comment: are there any errors showing up in your event viewer? are all features enabled on IIS? When running through Visual Studio, the configuration for IIS Express (which VS uses) is different to regular IIS. Is your web.config pointing at the correct locations?

Comment: we need the code where you bind grdDataBuffer

Comment: @user1666620 no errors on my event viewer and web.config is pointing the correct locations

Comment: can you place this code end of your IsPostback scope Response.Write("DV Count : " + dv.Count); and comment inside of UpdateClick, tell us if there are any data befor click and after click.

Comment: @Mert i see that there is data because i see it in the UI

Comment: what about after click on the button

Comment: @Mert this is from the log: `btnUpdateMashov_Click() start grdDataBuffer.Rows.Count: 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80645/discussion-between-mert-and-dasdas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So- weirdest thing ever- i recreated the asp page with all the controls and the code behind and everything worked fine- i guess that something just massed up in the old page designer and messed the whole thing up..

i don't know if it helps anyone- but sometimes when things that suppose to work- don't- maybe its worth checking if something changed in the designer.